# How to split delimited text in windows batch?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, text-processing

I have a batch file with an external configuration file. Say I needed to delete files specified in a configuration file as a **delimited list on one line**. The files could look like this:

```
[config.cfg]
*.pdb;*.config

[batch.bat]
...
for /f "tokens=* delims=;" %%b in (%DATA_10%) do (
CALL DEL "%%b%"
)
...
```

The batch code should iterate through the list of files and delete them.

If I have another external file assigned to %DATA_10% variable which contains the list of files to delete one per line then it works perfect. However what I need is the files to be extracted from config.cfg as you see above (all on one line) otherwise I would have too many config files required in my batch.

Any idea for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If config.cfg only contains one line with your data, you could use

```
set /p DATA_10= < config.cfg
```

But your FOR /F loop expands only once per line, so it can't work this way.
You could change it to

```
FOR %%a in (%DATA_10%) do (call del "%%b")
```

But you should be sure not to use * or ?, because they are interpreted as wildcards in a "normal" for-loop

Comment: Brilliant, it really worked using your normal for-loop without specifying a delimiter. I don't need to use wildcards now either since the delete works on folders too. Thanks for showing the right direction..